# Extract and save a slice from a volume with numpy

Tags: python, numpy, imaging, medical

I'm trying to extract a slice from a volume using numpy.
The volume is 512x512x132 and I want the slice number 66.
Each voxel is an unsigned 16-bit integer.

My code is:

```
import numpy

original = numpy.fromfile(filepath, dtype=numpy.uint16)
original = numpy.reshape(original, (512,512,132))

slice = original[:,:,66]

f = open('test.rawl', 'w')
slice.tofile(f)
f.close()
```

The code complete cleanly, but when I open the slice with an external program, it is not the slice data but garbage.

What I am doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: What external program opens numpy array files?

Comment: They are raw files, I use MANGO, it is a DICOM viewer that can also open raw data. I think to save as numpy arrays you have to use load() and save(). Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: `numpy.load()` and `numpy.save()` work only on a Numpy-specific file format that basically contains pickled array objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first problem is that you have your axes wrong.  Assuming you have 132 layers of 512x512 images you want to use:

```
original = numpy.fromfile(filepath, dtype=numpy.uint16).reshape((132, 512, 512))
```

Then for the slice take:

```
slc = original[66]
```

Also, binary data such as Numpy arrays use:

```
f = open('test.raw', 'wb')
```

The 'b' in the mode is for binary.  Otherwise Python will assume you're trying to write text and do things like convert newlines to the appropriate format for the system, among other things.

By the way, the `ndarray.tofile()` method also takes a filename, so unless you have a particular reason to it's not necessary to create a file handle first.  You can just use

```
arr.tofile('test.raw')
```

One final note: Try not to use `slice` as a variable.  That's a builtin name in Python and you could run into trouble by shadowing it with something else.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I applied your suggests but the problem remains. Can be a problem writing a Numpy View to file?

Comment: No, that wouldn't be the problem.  Without knowing more about what the data is supposed to look like or how it's shaped I don't think there's a better answer.

Are you sure the file you're reading in contains only the raw data?  And if so, is it written in C order?

Comment: I am sure it contains only raw data. If I write to file the original array it is the same as the raw input file. I am sure it is in C order. I am uploading an example.

Comment: Do you have matplotlib installed by any chance?  If so, what does it show if you do `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt; plt.imshow(slice)`?

Comment: I can't upload images, new user. But you can see here http://i50.tinypic.com/21o7ckn.png and http://i48.tinypic.com/8vw5c1.png. Same problem with matplotlib.

Comment: Oops, I see the problem. I'll update my answer with the other issue.